# Split Multidimensional Array into Smaller Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "__v": 0,
      "_create_date": "2014-08-20T23:00:12.901Z",
      "_id": "53f5287ca78473a969001827",
      "_last_message_date": "2014-08-20T23:04:36.347Z",
      "activity": 0,
      "blocked_users": [],
      "created_by": {
        "_id": "53e84b0eba84943c6d0003f8",
        "_last_modified": "2014-08-20T00:11:05.399Z",
        "first_name": "Jegg",
        "last_name": "V"
      },
      "curated": false,
      "diversity": 0,
      "featured": false,
      "flagged": false,
      "last_message": {
        "text": "let's talk beo",
        "created_by": {
          "_id": "53e84b0eba84943c6d0003f8",
          "first_name": "Jegg",
          "last_name": "V"
        },
        "_id": "53f52984a78473a969001833",
        "_create_date": "2014-08-20T23:04:36.347Z"
      },
      "member_count": 1,
      "messages_count": 1,
      "name": "Test",
      "public": true,
      "recency": 52182276.347,
      "score": 52182276.347,
      "tags": []
    },
```

This structure repeats over 3000 times creating a very large multidimensional array. I think I can use array_chunk($array, 300) to break the array into smaller chunks. But I can't figure out how to access them exactly.

What I want to do is independently loop through the newly chunked arrays. So I'd like to end up with something like:

```
$array1 = {...}
$array2 = {...}
$array3 = {...}
$array4 = {...}
```

... and so on

THen I could loop through each of the newly created arrays, which are essentially smaller groups of the original array, but of 3000 arrays in one multidimensional array as I have in the first place, I end up with these smaller ones of 300 arrays each.

I hope this makes sense, I'm kinda out of my league. Help is always appreciated.

Comment: That's not a PHP array. What part is repeated exactly ?

Comment: What is it you're hoping to gain by splitting the array up like that? I have to imagine a structure like this * 3000 plus 300 individual arrays would use a non-inconsequential amount of memory.

Comment: you can access the result array like `$resultarray[0]`,`$resultarray[1]` ..... `$resultarray[n]` where each `$resultarray[]` with 300 items

Comment: Yes, it's a JSON response decoded. I actually am not planning on running this on an active site, it's to be run on schedule to generate an HTML sitemap with the data in the JSON object. But I can't write more than 300 records per page for SEO reasons, so i need to create many different pages. My thought (which might be lame) is to loop through each new array and write out a separate HTML file for each limited to 300 per page. @bansi that might work, how could I get a count of how many chunks were created?

Comment: use [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) `count($resultarray)`

Comment: ahh... this might work. @bansi let me go play. thankyou!

Comment: come back if you get into any trouble

Comment: _“My thought (which might be lame) is to loop through each new array and write out a separate HTML file for each limited to 300 per page.”_ – that does not require _splitting_ the original array into smaller chunks; it would be enough to use _one_ loop and create a new HTML file whenever the loop counter reaches multiples of 300 …

Comment: @bansi it worked... pretty slick if I do say so myself, for a novice punk like me anyway. Basically built a tool that runs daily, gets all the "groups" created that day, which is over 3000 right now, but growing, then updates the sitemap index for the year, then creates individual pages each day depending on how many 300 link chunks were created, then updates the links to those pages for the daily index. If that makes any sense. Let's see how it works from an SEO perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I think your array is in json format.

First decode it and then pass to [**array_chunk**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) method.

```
array_chunk($input_array, 300));
```

then access them as `$input_array[0][0]`, `$input_array[0][1]`....... `$input_array[0][299]`, `$input_array[1][0]`, `$input_array[1][1]`.....

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: oh, somehow I entirely misread the question. `array_chunk` is something worth looking into.

---

You could try using `extract` to fetch array values to the "global" variable namespace.

`extract` takes three arguments: the array you wish to extract, flags, and prefix if needed.

I'm not sure how non-associative arrays are extracted, but you could try

```
$full_array = array(
    array( ... ),
    array( ... ),
    array( ... ),
    array( ... ),
    ...
);

// EXTR_PREFIX_ALL prefixes all extracted keys with wanted prefix (the third param).
$extract_amount = extract( $full_array, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'prefix' );
```

Now you should have the array extracted and available for use with variable names `$prefix0`, `$prefix1`, `$prefix2` and so on.

I'm not sure how smart it is to extract an array with hundreds of available values.